# Input field name is not populated on checkout page shipping address

Tags: magento2, checkout, shipping-address, magento2.3.2, magento2-cloud

I want to add a new field to my shipping address section on checkout page, I was able to achieve it by below code.

```
<item name="shippingAddress" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="shipping-address-fieldset" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="location" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Location</item>
                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">checkoutProvider</item>
                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="string">true</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">200</item>
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/form/field</item>
                        <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/form/element/input</item>
                        <item name="tooltip" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="description" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Search your location.</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </item>
</item>
```

The field is added to shipping address form but the `name` attribute is null. I need to set it as **location** but it always stays null. I have tried adding `name` and `inputName` attributes to xml but nothing seems to be working. Please check below as the html generated for my field.

```
<input class="input-text" type="text" data-bind="
    value: value,
    valueUpdate: 'keyup',
    hasFocus: focused,
    attr: {
        name: inputName,
        placeholder: placeholder,
        'aria-describedby': getDescriptionId(),
        'aria-required': required,
        'aria-invalid': error() ? true : 'false',
        id: uid,
        disabled: disabled
    }" name="" aria-invalid="false" id="YCYKNDR">
```

Do anyone have any idea how we can set `name` attribute for input field on shipping address section?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should check the official Magento Docs to add a new field to checkout.
Follow the docs to add the field so you can handle the data submission as well.

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/howdoi/checkout/checkout_new_field.html

The code you posted adds the field to checkout but you can't do much with it, it just renders it to the view.

Comment: Thank you Tsita for your answer. I have gone through magento devdocs as well as some other blogs but there is no configuration to set name in them.

Comment: Try adding the field using the first step from the link i have provided instead of xml and see if the name attribute gets populated.